# c++ template confusions

Tags: c++

I am writing some code using template,but i got some link errors:

> [Linker error] undefined reference to `Vector::Vector(Vector const&)'

But i wrote this function in a .cpp.Here is the code.

```
template <class T>

Vector<T>::Vector(Vector const& r)
{


m_nSize = r.size();
int i = 0;
m_pElements = new T[m_nSize];
    while(i <= m_nSize)
{
    m_pElements[i] = r[i];
    i++;
}
}
```

and it is declared here in .h:

```
template <class T>

class Vector
{

public:

Vector():m_nSize(0){ m_pElements = (T*)NULL; }
Vector(int size):m_nSize(size){ m_pElements = new T[size]; }
Vector(const Vector& r);
virtual ~Vector(){ delete m_pElements; }
T& operator[](int index){ return m_pElements[index];}
int size(){return m_nSize;}
int inflate(int addSize);
private:

    T *m_pElements;
    int m_nSize;
};
```

I'm really confused now...What should i do to correct is?

Comment: Related question: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/20984)

Answer (score 3):

[You should make implementations visible](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12). Move

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector const& r)
{
    //....
}
```

from the `cpp` file to the header.

Answer (score 2):

See the C++ faq (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13). Basically place the code in the header file.

Comment: Thanks for your help,the linkpage helps me a lot~